# Can you set up a FTP-server on windows using only commands?

Tags: windows, powershell, ansible, ftp, windows-10

I need to automate the build of a Windows10-VM (using packer/ansible), including a working FTP-site. The first step - enabling necessary windows features - can be done by using ansible's `win_feature`-module and could look like this (Edit: first solution only valid for Windows Server. Added second solution):

```
- name: Enable windows features required for setting up ftp
  win_feature:
    name: FTP Server
    state: present
    include_sub_features: true
    include_management_tools: true

- name: Enable windows features required for setting up ftp
  win_shell: Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName "IIS-FTPServer","IIS-FTPSvc" -all
```

The hard part, at least for me, is actually setting up the FTP-site. Since it has to be automated with ansible, I cannot use the GUI (IIS Management Console) like you normally would. Is there any way to accomplish this using only commands?

Comment: Looks like ansible modules for both [sites](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.8/modules/win_iis_website_module.html) and [bindings](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/windows/win_iis_webbinding_module.html) are available

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen thx, using these modules I was able to create a ftp-site. However, I still need to configure authentication (SSL needs to be disabled, all users should have read/write access etc). Do you have any idea where/how I could do that?